# If Operational error happens in django query in read database router, rerun the query on write database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

When a read query from read_db() router fails due to following error

```
ERROR: cancelling statement due to conflict with recovery
Detail: User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed
```

how to catch the error and retry the same query on a write db.

Comment: Show the stack trace and your code.

Comment: are you using an ORM or psycopg drivers ? and you are connecting to a single instance cluster? nothing in replication or HA like patroni ?

Answer (score -1):

Please note, this is not a Django problem, but PostgreSQL.

Two solutions are:

1. hot_standby_feedback OR
2. max_standby_archive_delay

See docs:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html